# Spring Security Roles at Multiple Levels

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm not sure if the title is correct. I have implemented Spring Security with roles in my Spring Boot Application. The authentication is using JWT.

```
Java - 8
Spring Boot - 2.7.2
```

Here is my scenario. The application is like having multiple departments. Each department has multiple teams.  The department will have a department manager, the Team will have a Team manager and there will be users in Team. Also, there will be Admin users who can manage all the departments and teams. So I have entity classes for all and user entity for managers, admin users, and normal users. Also implemented roles - SUPER_ADMIN, DEPT_ADMIN, TEAM_ADMIN & USER.

- SUPER_ADMIN - Admin users. Allow all CRUD operations of all APIs
- DEPT_ADMIN - The Department manager. Allows CRUD operations of
  Department & Teams and also manage users
- TEAM_ADMIN - The Team    Manager. Allows CRUD operations of the Team
  & and also manage users
- USER - Manage own user profile.

With this, I have implemented Spring Security and added PreAuthorize for all APIs with relevant roles, and is working fine.

Now what I would need is, DEPT_ADMIN user should be able to manage all items within their department only, not Teams and users of other departments. Similarly, TEAM_ADMIN user shall be able to manage all items within their own team only. Not other teams.

Below are a few of my sample APIs with the current implementation. There are many items under Dept and many items under Teams which shall be managed by users only within their dept/team.

```
public class UserData implements UserDetails {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String password;
    @Getter
    private final UserModel userModel;
    @Getter
    private final String userId;
    @Getter
    private final String deptId;
    @Getter
    private final String roleName;
    @Getter
    private final String teamId;
    private final String username;
    private final Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private final boolean accountNonExpired;
    private final boolean accountNonLocked;
    private final boolean credentialsNonExpired;
    private final boolean enabled;
    
}
```

**Controller**

```
@PutMapping("/dept/{id}")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('SUPER_ADMIN','DEPT_ADMIN')")
public ResponseEntity<?> editDept(@RequestBody DeptRequest request, @PathVariable("id") String id) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserData principal = (UserData) authentication.getPrincipal();
    String currentRole = principal.getRoleName();
    String currentDeptId = principal.getDeptId();
    if(currentRole.equals(RoleConstant.SUPER_ADMIN) || (currentRole.equals(RoleConstant.DEPT_ADMIN) && principal.getDeptId().equals(id))) {
        //response = service call
        return new ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    } else {
        throw new ServiceDeniedException("You do not belong to the department")
    }
}
 
    @PutMapping("/teams")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('SUPER_ADMIN','DEPT_ADMIN', 'TEAM_ADMIN')")
public ResponseEntity<?> editTeam(@RequestBody TeamRequest request) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserData principal = (UserData) authentication.getPrincipal();
    String currentRole = principal.getRoleName();
    String currentDeptId = principal.getDeptId();
    String currentTeamId = principal.getTeamId();
    if(currentRole.equals(RoleConstant.SUPER_ADMIN) || (currentRole.equals(RoleConstant.DEPT_ADMIN) && currentDeptId.equals(currentDeptId)) || currentRole.equals(RoleConstant.TEAM_ADMIN) && currentTeamId.equals(request.getTeamId()))) {
        //response = service call
        return new ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    } else {
        throw new ServiceDeniedException("You do not belong to the department/Team")
    }
}
```

The condition is added in each method in controller/service layer. Is there any better way that can be handled at the *PreAuthorize* level or something instead of checking in each method?